# pyspark replace column values with when function gives column object is not callable

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like this

```
name
----
A
B
ccc
D
eee
```

and a list of valid names

```
legal_names = [A, B, D]
```

And I want to replace all illegal names with another string "INVALID".

I used this script:

```
(
    df.withColumn(
        "name",
        F.when((F.col("name").isin(legal_names)), F.col("name")).otherwhise(
            F.lit("INVALID")
        ),
    )
)
```

But I get this error

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-4397929369165676>:4, in <cell line: 2>()
      1 (
      2     df.withColumn(
      3         "name",
----> 4         F.when((F.col("name").isin(legal_names)), F.col("name")).otherwhise(
      5             F.lit("INVALID")
      6         ),
      7     )
      8 )

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Dummy data to reproduce:

```
vals = [("A", ), ("B", ), ("ccc", ), ("D", ), ("EEE", )]
cols = ["name"]
legal_names = ["A", "B", "D"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, cols)
```

Comment: This is going to be painful, better sit down... `otherwise` with no `h` after the `w` :-)

Comment: oh my oh my....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code -

```
df1 = df.withColumn( "name", F.when( (F.col("name").isin(*legal_names)), F.col("name") ).otherwise(F.lit('INVALID'))  )
```

**Output :**

```
+-------+
|   name|
+-------+
|      A|
|      B|
|INVALID|
|      D|
|INVALID|
+-------+
```